# How to mark dates if they are older than 5 days in perl?

Tags: perl

I know how to mark dates as YELLOW that are in the past:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pe '
    BEGIN {$today = localtime->ymd." ".localtime->hms}
    @days = $_ =~ /<td>([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})<\/td>/g;
    for $d (@days) {
      $_ =~ s!$d!<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:yellow>$d</font>!g if $d lt $today;
      }' foo.html > foo-TMP.html
mv foo-TMP.html foo.html
```

**Question:** But how can I **only** mark dates that are older then 5 days?

Example:

```
It's: 2014.07.20 15:00
```

So the following example dates would be marked as yellow:

```
bla-bla random string here<td>2014.05.21 16:32</td>bla-bla random string here
bla-bla random string here<td>2014.07.15 14:59</td>bla-bla random string here
```

And the following should be left alone:

```
bla-bla random string here<td>2014.07.15 15:01</td>bla-bla random string here
bla-bla random string here<td>2014.07.18 19:14</td>bla-bla random string here
```

Comment: Please mark the relevant dates using a class and a CSS file, rather than embedding CSS directly into your HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Time::Piece docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece), "using localtime/gmtime in the way documented in perlfunc will still return what you expect", and [the perlfunc docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) reveal that `localtime()` takes an argument, a number of seconds since the epoch, the default (if you don't provide one) being the return value of `time()`.

Five days is 432000 seconds. If you change the initial reference point:

```
BEGIN {
    $then = localtime(time() - 432000);
    $day = $then->ymd." ".$then->hms
}
```

And use `$day` in place of `$today`, you should get what you want.

Comment: If you `use Time::Seconds` first (it's a companion module to `TIme::Piece`) you can use `ONE_DAY * 5` instead of the magical `432000`. Also, you don't have to call `time`, as `Time::Piece` overloads integer arithmetic and you can just write `my $then = localtime() - ONE_DAY * 5`